# Why UITapGestureRecognizer sends to selector's function parameter itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Why UITapGestureRecognizer sends to selector's function parameter itself while there is now parameter pasted in function call ?

```
 blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))


  func handleDismiss(setting: Setting){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

        }

    }, completion: {
        (completed: Bool) in



        if setting.name != "" && setting.name != "Cancel"  {
            self.homeController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
        }
    })

}
```

so when i tap the view it calls this function but there is no actual parameter pasted inside function call so gesturerecognizer send to parameter intself  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz964D-WrU9KT1RDenFGbktLVEE here is debug picture.

Comment: from where you are passing this `setting` parameter?can you please show that part of code?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz964D-WrU9Kd1lOaUZZcXZPaE0 & of course while tapping gesture occurs

Comment: Yes not need to send any parameter to gesture selector because the selector has default gesture as parameter

Comment: obviously) but why?

Comment: All what you need is info about the the object that has the selector so in our case you have all info about you  TapGestureRecognizer,like isEnabled

Comment: what are the true intention to do that? Please dot put foolish answers if you don't know what to say | not to @Hosny

Comment: @Hosny what about parameters? If function don't get them at run time it simply won't carry out?

Comment: Look as example in Button action you just need info about button (sender) so you no need to pass it if you need add action programmatically and this like our case of gesture you have all info about gesture

Comment: @Hosny and what about function at runtime? it simply won't executing?

Comment: Your selector should look like this handleDismiss(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) and then use the info of tapGesture , and note that tapGesture is UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)) that you added for blackView

Comment: You can't use this type of parameter. The `UITapGestureRecognizer` uses their own parameter.

Comment: Your selector should look like this handleDismiss(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) and then use the info of tapGesture , and note that tapGesture is UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)) nice very useful thanks but then if we wont pass any parameters in selectors handle dismiss why app won't crash?

Comment: @ Mannopson  already used works fine

Comment: If your problem is solved, please add the answer, so others can take help, thanks